# How to insert the string before of '@' in the email address?

Tags: java

I'm getting email address like `user.q@stackoverflow.com`. I want to add string before '@' symbol of email address in java.

After added string in the email address : `user.qzzz@stackoverflow.com`. How to insert 'zzz' string before @ symbol in java ?

Comment: With a combination of `substring` calls and String concatenations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String input = "zzz";

String email = "user.q@stackoverflow.com";

int at = email.indexOf('@');

String newEmail = email.substring(0, at) + input + email.substring(at);
```

Answer (score 5):

This will find the index of the at-sign:

```
 int index = emailString.indexOf("@");
```

This will give you the first part of the string, before the at-sign:

```
String firstPart = emailString.substring(0, index);
```

This will give you the end part, starting with the at-sign

```
String lastPart = emailString.substring(index);
```

Put the bits together with your new stuff to make the result.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, though not super efficient:

```
String s = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@")-1)+"ZZZ"+email.substring(email.indexOf(@));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using the split method of strings to get both sides of the string.

```
String email = "user.q@stackoverflow.com";
String[] strList = email.split("@");
strList[0] += "zzz";
email = strList[0] + "@" + strList[1];
System.out.println(email);
```